# Problem with Jersey Inject HK2 2.27: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, rest, jersey, hk2

I open this post because I have a problem after updating Jersey version from 2.25 to 2.27.

During updating, Jersey asked me to add jersey-hk2 Maven Dependency.

I received ClassCastException when trying to send a POST request with a RestClient like in the box below, despite the same instruction worked fine in Jersey 2.25:

```
WebTarget webTarget = client.target(resource);
Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                             .post(Entity.entity(data, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

This is the entire exception I received:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory to org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.InjectionManagerFactory
at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder$LazyObjectIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:714)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lookupService(Injections.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lookupInjectionManagerFactory(Injections.java:97)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:68)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:432)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:826)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getConfiguration(ClientRequest.java:285)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.validateHttpMethodAndEntity(JerseyInvocation.java:143)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:108)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:445)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:351)
at com.mypackage.utils.REST.RestClient.executePost(RestClient.java:118)
```

I specify that, as suggested in other questions posted on the web, I matched all the versions of Jersey components to 2.27.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Unfortunately since Jersey moved to a pluggable DI framework format a lot of these sort of issues come up.  The only thing I can suggest is use mvn dependency:tree and see if somewhere else in your dependency graph there are older version of the Jersey libraries

Comment: Thank you jwells131313. As you suggested I checked all Jersey dependencies and all of them where already at 2.27 version.

Comment: [SOLVED] The problem was not due to Jersey or HK2. My post request was called into a parallel lambda expression and it probabilly caused problems. So I solved changing lambda into a serial stream.